# Excel: Sort by equation stopping at the last filled row

Tags: excel, sorting

I have a table A:T, i want to write an equation to sort the table automatically by the column N whenever the data is updated, taking in consideration the following conditions:

1. The cells range is extended to row 5000 so as to be modified once
   data is updated.
2. I want the sort to be stopped at last filled row in the table not for all of the 5000 rows as the 5000 rows are filled with zeros.

My simple existing equation now is:

```
=SORTBY('Rate of Purchasing'!A3:T5000,'Rate of Purchasing'!N3:N5000,-1)

=SORTBY('Rate of Purchasing'!A3:T5000, IF(ROW('Rate of Purchasing'!N3:N5000)<=MAX(IF('Rate of Purchasing'!N3:N5000<>"", ROW('Rate of Purchasing'!N3:N5000))), 'Rate of Purchasing'!N3:N5000), -1)
(failed)

=SORT(FILTER('Rate of Purchasing'!A3:T5000, 'Rate of Purchasing'!N3:N5000<>""), ROW('Rate of Purchasing'!N3:N5000), -1) 
(failed)
```

Comment: so what's your actual issue?  What doesn't work about what you tied?

Comment: The absence of both data and desired output makes helping you more difficult. If I understand what you have written, the following will return the relevant rows by looking for the last non-zero numeric entry in Column A: `=$A$3:INDEX($A$3:$T$5000,LOOKUP(9.9E+307,1/$A$3:$A$5000,ROW($A$3:$A$5000)-2),0)`. Adapt to your actual situation.

Answer (score 0):

If your data looks like a table use a table.

Highlight your data and press `Ctrl`+`T` to turn it into a table.  When a cell within the table is selected an extra ribbon called *Table* will appear on your toolbar.  You can then rename your table as required.
Your formula will only look at the data in the table and any formula in the actual table will also extend as you add new rows.

Your formula would then just be:  `=SORTBY(Table1,Table1[Heading1])`

[Overview of Excel tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)

[image]